# how to make button clickable but its parent div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am  trying to trigger a function when a button inside a div is clicked and another function when the div is clicked.When I am clicking the `button` `div` is also getting clicked.how to make `div` not clickable when button is clicked

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div style="width:400px;height:400px;background:blue" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-click="divC()">


<button ng-click="myfun()" style="float:right;top:0">
CLICK
</button>


</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.count = 0;
$scope.myfun = function(){
alert("button")
};
$scope.divC = function(){
alert("div")
};
});
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use `event.stopPropagation()`, this will stop the click bubbling up to its containers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div style="width:400px;height:400px;background:blue" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-click="divC()">


<button ng-click="myfun($event)" style="float:right;top:0">
CLICK
</button>


</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.count = 0;
$scope.myfun = function(event){
event.stopPropagation();
alert("button")
};
$scope.divC = function(){
alert("div")
};
});
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: plz see the question.I want to see only button in the alert when button is clicked

Comment: @kevin That's what Neil did! Click "Run code snippet" to see.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the [event propagation.](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Change your button function to this:

```
$scope.myfun = function(){
  event.stopPropagation();
  alert("button")
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div style="width:400px;height:400px;background:blue; z-index:-999;" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-click="divC()">


<button ng-click="myfun()" style="float:right;top:0; z-index:100">
CLICK
</button>


</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.count = 0;
$scope.myfun = function(){
event.stopPropagation();
alert("button")
};

$scope.divC = function(){
alert("div")
};
});
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please see the question.I want to only myfun have to execute when button is clicked

Comment: @kevin- you wanted only the button to alert when the button was clicked, correct? I did that

Comment: no.divC is getting triggered when button is clicked.I want myfun to be triggered

Comment: @kevin- this might be your computer? What browser are you using? It works fine for me, and I've tried it with Chrome and Firefox

Comment: no please understand the question properly.I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `event` object(e) and use it's `target` property to determine the `click` event is invoked by which element.

```
$("div").on("click", function(e)
{
  var target = $(e.target);
  if(target.is('button'))
     alert('button clicked');
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/g4pr4LL9/